# JavaScript print . Как распечатать документ без лишних footer header

Tags: javascript, print

Как распечатать документ без footer и header. Не знаю как это по другому назвать, поэтому прошу прощение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался использовать данный код - не помогает.

```
 @media print {
       @page { margin: 0; }
       body { margin: 1.6cm; }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Он помогает, просто интересный факт, что не всегда он скрывает эти надписи...
Но можно их скрыть в ручную, при переключении "Фоновой графики" в "Дополнительных настройках" (можешь хоть два раза нажать), то этот параметр обновиться и уберутся надписи.

> Если ты это сможешь реализовать это  кодом, то прошу в комментариях мне скинуть пример, а то сам над этим работаю и не знаю как автоматизировать данный процесс.